# Determine if a function is called with null, undefined, or the global object in non-strict mode

Tags: javascript

I am looking to throw a `TypeError` whenever a particular function in non-strict mode is called with `null` / `undefined`. There is a partial workaround by forcing the function to locally execute in strict mode, but it's an incomplete solution.

```js
var t = function(s) { console.log(this) };
t.call(null), t.call(undefined); // window, window

(function() {
    "use strict";
    t = function(s) { console.log(this) }

    t.call(null), t.call(undefined); // null, undefined
})();
```

I also can't throw if `this` is `window`, as the function may be legitimately called with `this` as the global object. Is there a complete workaround not involving `use strict`?

Comment: Would wrapping the function `t` to produce a modified function be an option? Eg: `t = wrap(t)`, then you can use `t` normally, except it would throw when you call it with `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Wouldn't `wrap` have the same problems as `t`? That is, you can't distinguish whether it was called with `null`, `undefined`, or `window`.

Comment: If you return a modifed function with does some checks when call is invoked, then you can change the behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/cpn1dh8t/

Comment: That's pretty clever. Perhaps you should make it an answer ;-)

Comment: Why don't you just want to use strict mode for that function? I don't see what's incomplete about your solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get the original `null` or `undefined` thisArgument in a sloppy-mode function. You must wrap your function in a strict mode one.

Notice that not the strictness in the call location is important for this, but only the definition of your function. You want

```js
function t() {
    "use strict";
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(this)
};

// calls in sloppy mode:
t(), t.call(null), t.call(undefined); // undefined, null, undefined

(function() {
    "use strict";
    // calls in strict mode:
    t(), t.call(null), t.call(undefined); // undefined, null, undefined
})();
```